# How to start PostgREST as a ubuntu service in a cloud server?

Tags: postgrest

According to PostgREST doc, we can start postgrest with

```
postgrest postgres://user:pass@host:port/db -a anon_user [other flags]
```

It is fine to run locally; however, how to register it as a system service and run in the cloud server?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to have a init (shell) script (just like every other system service)

This script no longer works because the structure of the github repository changed and some files are not there anymore, but you can get a basic idea of what needs to happen
https://github.com/ruslantalpa/blogdemo/blob/master/provision/postgrest.sh
the init scripts can be found here
https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest/tree/5d904dfd66c75133f2383eefbfa8b152a669625e/debian